# Liferay 7.3 adt

Tags: freemarker, adt, liferay-7.3

Can anyone help me with this error i get when i create a adt template in liferay 7.3?

```
Denied access to method or field setAttribute of class org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest
```

it shows in this line of my adt

```
${request.setAttribute("viewURL", viewURL )}
```

Adt works fine in my liferay 7.2 version, Also I can see contents of asset publisher only when i am logged in as admin.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

it's probably due to the default restrictions. Try this:

- go to control panel, configuration, system settings, template engines, freemarker.
- there is probably one restricted class with value org.apache.*, if you remove that restriction, it should work.

About the problem with asset publisher, check if Guest user is assigned the permission to view the contents you are showing in the asset publisher, and reindex the site (as asset publisher uses the elastic index to show results)